# Using onblur() event for textbox in mvc razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a javascript code for a textbox to accept commas(,) but restrict a comma only at the end of the line.For this I am using the javascript onblur() event,but I am not getting the output.Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
function checkForComma(keyCode) {
if (event.keyCode == 44) {
    alert('Not allowed');
}
}
```

And the EditorTemplate:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, @Model.isUsed ? (object)new { @class = "form-control" } : new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @onblur = "return checkForComma(event)" })
```

Comment: sumedha, do you want where the commas in between the value are removed, or at the end?

Comment: Commas in between the values should be there but should be removed at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, using `onblur`,you can do

```js
function checkForComma(element) {
  if(element.value.substr(element.value.length-1) == ','){
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, element.value.length - 1);
        alert('Not allowed');
      }
    }
```

```html
<input onblur="checkForComma(this)"/>
```

Comment: I think OP wants the string to not end in a comma

Comment: keypress restricts comma even in between the string.I want the commas to be there inbetween the string but should show an alert when a comma is put at the end of the string

Comment: @sumedha, if you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input').focusout(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.slice(-1) == ',') alert('not allowed');

});
```

Here we are getting the value of the `input` when they leave the field (`focusout`), and then checking whether the last letter of the string is a comma.

***[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ozn3uso4/)***

Comment: This works but it does not work properly.When I add a comma at the end of the string,the first time it does not show an alert.When I click again on the textbox and then exit it shows the alert.

Comment: @sumedha The first time you exit, you will get the alert, and every subsequent time. Otherwise your user would never be able to enter commas